# How can I do almost any integration with the Leibniz and Euler's intuitive concept that integration is the sum of infinite number of "Differentials"?

Tags: differential-forms

Is it correct that integration of $f(x)dx$ with limit $'a'$ to $'b'$ $$=f(a)dx+f(a+dx)dx+f(a+2dx)dx+f(a+3dx)dx+...+f(b-dx)dx?$$Can we calculate any integration with only this view (not use any integration rule as 'Anti differentiation')?Euler intuitively stated 'Integration' as 'Anti-Differentials'(not anti derivative).

Comment: Please make your question more CLEAR!!

Comment: Does integration act as anti differentiation or Anti-differential ? Does my above mention 'expression of an integration' correct?If not,please mention why?Above all,my question is can we integrate a function with the help of the view 'to sum all differential somehow' but not any help of some regular described integration 'rule' in somebook?

Answer (score 1):

If $f:\>[a,b]\to{\mathbb R}$, or $\to{\mathbb C}$, is continuous then one can prove that
$$\int_a^b f(x)\>dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}{b-a\over N}\>\sum_{k=1}^N f\left(a+{k(b-a)\over N}\right)\ .\tag{1}$$
But it is only in special cases that an integral can be computed in this way. Examples are linear functions $f(x):=px+q$, where you have to sum an arithmetic series, or $f(x):=x^2+px+q$, if you know the formula for the sum of all squares from $1$ to $N^2$. Other examples can be related to geometric series, e.g. $f(x):=e^{\lambda x}$, whereby $\lambda$ may also be complex. In this way you can, e.g.,  compute the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x\>dx=1$.

It is the fantastic power of the FTC that it allows the computation of an integral $\int_a^b f(x)\>dx$ by purely "algebraic" formulas whenever you are able to name a primitive $F$ of $f$.

Comment: But is my above expression wrong? If it so,please mention why?

Comment: My (now corrected) expression on the RHS of $(1)$ corresponds to yours with $dx={b-a\over N}$. In any case, there is some limit involved.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!... But in your equation 1) should it not start with k=0 rather than k=1?Because if we start from k=1 then the first term will be (b-a/N)f(a+(b-a/N) but according to my above mentioned expression the first term should be (b-a/N)f(a).